# Internet Explorer 9, 10 & 11 Event constructor doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, dom-events, custom-events

I am creating an event, so use the DOM Event constructor:

```
new Event('change');
```

This works fine in modern browsers, however in Internet Explorer 9, 10 & 11, it fails with:

```
Object doesn't support this action
```

How can I fix Internet Explorer (ideally via a polyfill)? If I can't, is there a workaround I can use?

Comment: "how can I fix Internet Explorer?" xD

Answer (score 187, accepted):

There's an [IE polyfill for the CustomEvent constructor at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent). Adding CustomEvent to IE and using that instead works.

```
(function () {
  if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false; //If not IE

  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   }

  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();
```

Comment: You sir saved my life. Would it be safe to make a complete substitution? I mean, doing `window.Event= CustomEvent` on the last line.

Comment: In IE11 it seems to be safe to set window.Event = CustomEvent, yes.

Comment: For anybody interested it seems to be possible to detect you are in IE (for this case) by checking typeof(Event) which is 'function' for all except IE where it is 'object'.  You can then safely polyfill the Event constructor using the approach above.

Comment: I'm just investigating similar workaround for `StorageEvent` and `typeof(StorageEvent)` doesn't work in MS Edge. This works: `try { new StorageEvent(); } catch (e) { /* polyfill */ }`.

Comment: It might not be safe to substitute window.CustomEvent, if you are using third party libraries which uses IE defined CustomEvent constructor.

Comment: In IE you need to place this block of code at the very top before it is needed for instantiation.

Comment: Refer here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

Comment: I had to to some adjustments, but this is definitely the solution. Saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed the polyfill on MDN doesn't have this line: `CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;` -- what's the purpose of adding this line?

Answer (score 68):

I think that the best solution to solve your problem and deal with cross-browser event creation is:

```
function createNewEvent(eventName) {
    var event;
    if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
        event = new Event(eventName);
    } else {
        event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    }
    return event;
}
```

Comment: It works! I just think it should `return event` so I can pass it to `dispatchEvent()`.

Comment: `initEvent` is old and [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent), you need to at least use the modern way and as a fallback, use the deprecated way.

Comment: @vsync It might be deprecated, but the docs you linked to say "Instead use specific event constructors, like Event()", which is _exactly_ what this is trying to polyfill, so there's no choice really.

Comment: `CustomEvent` allows to pass custom data through `detail` option, and `Event` doesn't. Am I wrong?

Comment: CustomEvent is not supported for IE9, 10 or 11 either per my own experience. The only good answer seems to be the accepted.

Answer (score 4):

This package does the magic:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-event-polyfill

Include the package and dispatch the event as following:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new window.CustomEvent('some-event'))
```

Comment: 95 dependencies?

Comment: @DamienRoche Could it be you missread "Dependents" as "Dependencies"? Because the package actually has 0 dependencies and (by the time of writing) 102 dependents (i.e., packages that depend on it). That 102 dependent packages probably were 95 back in july.

Comment: I bloody well did! :P

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to dispatch a simple event like the HTML toggle event, this works in Internet Explorer 11 as well as the other browsers:

```
let toggle_event = null;
try {
    toggle_event = new Event("toggle");
}
catch (error) {
    toggle_event = document.createEvent("Event");
    let doesnt_bubble = false;
    let isnt_cancelable = false;
    toggle_event.initEvent("toggle", doesnt_bubble, isnt_cancelable);
}
// disclosure_control is a details element.
disclosure_control.dispatchEvent(toggle_event);
```

Comment: can't see why you are mixing `es6` `let` (and not use `var`) with a code supposed to run on old IE.. it might confuse beginners who will copy-paste this

Comment: @vsync *shrug* I *did* mention the version number. My personal website was only targeting IE11 last year, so it never occurred to me to check support in older versions. (As of today, I serve IE11 plain HTML without stylesheets or scripts. People need to move on.)

In any case, the only version of Internet Explorer still supported by Microsoft as of 2017 April is version 11, so it's a bit of a moot point. I’d not encourage anyone to use an unsupported browser by targeting it. The Web can be a dangerous place.

Comment: it's not about that at all, and not about trying to change the world or anything. For example, the title for the question specifically asks for `IE 9` and above, and perhaps a person seeking an answer who finds this thread, is developing an app for legacy banking system or some other system for business clients which have no control over their computers and are obliged to work with old IE. this has nothing to do with Microsoft Support..

Answer (score 3):

the `custom-event` npm package worked beautifully for me

https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-event

```
var CustomEvent = require('custom-event');

// add an appropriate event listener
target.addEventListener('cat', function(e) { process(e.detail) });

// create and dispatch the event
var event = new CustomEvent('cat', {
  detail: {
    hazcheeseburger: true
  }
});
target.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but there's already another NPM package mentioned as an answer.

Comment: What's wrong with giving users a variety of options?

Comment: A more generic package is https://www.npmjs.com/package/events-polyfill

Answer (score 3):

There's a polyfill service which can patch this and others for you

https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/

```
 <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally use a wrapper function to handle manually created events. The following code will add a static method on all `Event` interfaces (all global variables ending in `Event` are an Event interface) and allow you to call functions like `element.dispatchEvent(MouseEvent.create('click'));` on IE9+.

```
(function eventCreatorWrapper(eventClassNames){
    eventClassNames.forEach(function(eventClassName){
        window[eventClassName].createEvent = function(type,bubbles,cancelable){
            var evt
            try{
                evt = new window[eventClassName](type,{
                    bubbles: bubbles,
                    cancelable: cancelable
                });
            } catch (e){
                evt = document.createEvent(eventClassName);
                evt.initEvent(type,bubbles,cancelable);
            } finally {
                return evt;
            }
        }
    });
}(function(root){
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(root).filter(function(propertyName){
        return /Event$/.test(propertyName)
    });
}(window)));
```

**EDIT:** The function to find all `Event` interfaces can also be replaced by an array to alter only the Event interfaces you need (`['Event', 'MouseEvent', 'KeyboardEvent', 'UIEvent' /*, etc... */]`).