# Correct way to dispatch event in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, internet-explorer-11, dispatch

I have a problem with dispatching event in Internet Explorer 11.
Currently, we have:

`fireEvent`
for IE
and

```
createEvent
initEvent
dispatchEvent
```

idiom for normal browsers.

The prorblem is that neither of these works in IE 11. Nor do the new way - using `new Event()` / `new CustomEvent()`.

It looks like Microsoft deprecated their proprietary `fireEvent` (for IE 11) but 
did not offer support for correct dispatching.

PS. I believe i have read all topics here on SO related to the matter still can't find the working solution

Comment: Isn't this the kind of thing that jquery is for? To abstract all of the weirdness and non-working things out so that you can just call [.trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) ....See also [this page](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Looks promising, i'll try it when i'll be at work

Comment: @LynnCrumbling The solution you proposed works flawlessly! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here's a fully working solution I based on this SO Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49071358/79677

You can use it like this: `SendBrowserAgnosticEvent(myElement, 'change')`
and it will return the created `Event` object

Here's the code in JavaScript

```js
/** This allows us to dispatch browser events in old IE and newer browsers */
export var SendBrowserAgnosticEvent = function(elem, eventName) {
    //Needed for IE Support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent#Browser_Compatibility
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/49071358/79677
    var event;
    if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
        event = new Event(eventName);
    } else {
        event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    }
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);

    return event;
};
```

and here it is in TypeScript with full typings

```js
/** This allows us to dispatch browser events in old IE and newer browsers */
export const SendBrowserAgnosticEvent = <T extends HTMLElement | Window>(elem: T, eventName: string): Event => {
    //Needed for IE Support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent#Browser_Compatibility
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/49071358/79677
    let event;
    if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
        event = new Event(eventName);
    } else {
        event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    }
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);

    return event;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your code written in TypeScript. It was useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question (thanks to the @LynnCrumbling for pointing out):

Browser specific event firing behavior better to replace with unified jQuery call like:

```
var eventObject = jQuery.Event("change"); // event you need to fire
$(targetObject).trigger(eventObject);
```

Comment: Awesome! And kudos for posting an answer.