# dispatchEvent not working on edge

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, microsoft-edge

In my angular application I have to opened a new window and dispatched an event back to the controller .The code is working on Chrome and Firefox but it does not work for **Edge**

Below is the code from the external file

```
try {
   var ev = new Event('abc');
   ev['data'] = model;
   window.opener.dispatchEvent(ev);
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

In the external window i get the alert **ERROR:invalid argument.**

in the angular component i have the listener

```
@HostListener('window:abc', ['$event'])
```

Couldn't get much info from other answers.

Please Guide
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176983/dispatchevent-not-working-in-ie11

Comment: tried the answer there but it still says invalid argument..what could be invalid.

Comment: are you creating custom event?

Comment: @Chellappan: yes custom event.I tried with  var ev = new CustomEvent('socialSuccess'); as well

Comment: `var myObj = {foo: "bar"};
var event = new Event("eventName");
event.data = myObj;
div.dispatchEvent(event);` take this as a reference and check.

Comment: @Madhu:I commented out the data part and still it was returning the same error. I'll try this anyway.

Comment: if you could use jquery then here is a solution `href_window.$(href_window.document).trigger(customEvent);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the disptachEvent.It was because the child window was losing the scope of the parent angular component from which it was opened.
To solve this i found the solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296704/angular2-how-to-call-component-function-from-outside-the-app/35297044#35297044).

Before opening the child window we must set the reference of angularComponentRef

```
window['angularComponentRef'] = {component: this, zone: _ngZone};
```