# Emulate a space bar keypress

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've searched everywhere, read the docs on MDN, but I can't seem to solve this problem.

I want to emulate the client pressing the <kbd>space</kbd> bar using JavaScript.

I've tried:

```
var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
e.which = e.keyCode = 32; // 32 is the keycode for the space bar
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

However this hasn't worked for whatever reason; if the following event handler is put before the above code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev){
  console.log(ev.which);
});
```

`0` is logged to the console.

For some reason, the event is triggered but the key is always `0`

Can someone help me fix it?

Comment: @Satpal The API used in the answer there is deprecated now. I have tried using the answer but it failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do on this way

`var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'keyCode':32,'which':32});`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5se13tmg/

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Comment: Warning for others finding this: this is not IE compatible. There is more discussion on how to get around that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596123/internet-explorer-9-10-11-event-constructor-doesnt-work

Answer (score 5):

Create your event variable like that :

```
var e = new Event('keydown');
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/zw7d7d61/

Comment: Better JSfiddle, we can see something there.