# Event constructor in worker on IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, web-worker, polyfills, custom-events

`new Event` does not work in IE11, and unfortunately neither does the polyfill from MDN and this question: [Internet Explorer 9, 10 & 11 Event constructor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596123/internet-explorer-9-10-11-event-constructor-doesnt-work), since they rely on `document.createEvent`.

Are there any workarounds for creating custom events in the worker context?

Comment: Why would you need a DOM event in a worker?

Comment: I'm using [Robust Websocket](https://github.com/appuri/robust-websocket) and it requires `CustomEvent` to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use a method which aliases an implementation of an existing event system. For example:

```
    sinon.Event = function Event(type, bubbles, cancelable, target) {
        this.initEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable, target);
    };

    sinon.Event.prototype = {
        initEvent: function (type, bubbles, cancelable, target) {
            this.type = type;
            this.bubbles = bubbles;
            this.cancelable = cancelable;
            this.target = target;
        },

        stopPropagation: function () {},

        preventDefault: function () {
            this.defaultPrevented = true;
        }
    };

    sinon.CustomEvent = function CustomEvent(type, customData, target) {
        this.initEvent(type, false, false, target);
        this.detail = customData.detail || null;
    };

    sinon.CustomEvent.prototype = new sinon.Event();

    sinon.CustomEvent.prototype.constructor = sinon.CustomEvent;

    sinon.EventTarget = {
        addEventListener: function addEventListener(event, listener) {
            this.eventListeners = this.eventListeners || {};
            this.eventListeners[event] = this.eventListeners[event] || [];
            push.call(this.eventListeners[event], listener);
        },

        removeEventListener: function removeEventListener(event, listener) {
            var listeners = this.eventListeners && this.eventListeners[event] || [];

            for (var i = 0, l = listeners.length; i < l; ++i) {
                if (listeners[i] === listener) {
                    return listeners.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        },

        dispatchEvent: function dispatchEvent(event) {
            var type = event.type;
            var listeners = this.eventListeners && this.eventListeners[type] || [];

            for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
                if (typeof listeners[i] === "function") {
                    listeners[i].call(this, event);
                } else {
                    listeners[i].handleEvent(event);
                }
            }

            return !!event.defaultPrevented;
        }
    };
}


/**
 * Used to bind event listeners to the worker. Internally it uses the jQuery `.on` method.
 * @method on
 * @param {Mixed} args* Lookup the jQuery `.on` API for argument list.
 * @chainable
 */

var worker = new WebWorker('./worker-script.js');
worker.on('my-custom-event', function () {
console.log('custom event triggered!');
});
```

**References**

- [jQuery github repo: sinon.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery/master/external/sinon/sinon.js)
- [web-worker/web-worker.js at master · tanzeelkazi/web-worker](https://github.com/tanzeelkazi/web-worker/blob/master/src/js/web-worker.js)
- [Improving Web Worker usage in PWA's (and an implementation in PureScript)](https://frigoeu.github.io/vdomworker.html)
- [peter.michaux.ca - Anonymous Events - Extremely Loose Coupling](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/anonymous-events-extremely-loose-coupling)
- [John Resig - Flexible Javascript Events](https://johnresig.com/projects/flexible-javascript-events/)
- [... and the winner is ... - QuirksBlog](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/10/_and_the_winner_1.html)