# Javascript - IE automation - event is undefined error

Tags: javascript, events, custom-events

I am trying to trigger a series of events on an element in Internet Explorer but the following code gives me an "Event is undefined". any ideas what can be done to address this? createEvent is not supported by the object so cannot be used.

```js
function categoryClick() {
  var events = ["mousemove", "mouseover", "focus", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"];
  var combobox = document.getElementById("category");
  var a = combobox.childNodes;
  var target = a[0].childNodes[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var eventObject = new Event(events[i], {
      "bubbles": true,
      "cancelable": false
    });

    target.dispatchEvent(eventObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer 9, 10 & 11 Event constructor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596123/internet-explorer-9-10-11-event-constructor-doesnt-work)

Comment: `event = event || window.event;` That makes no sense why it is there....

Comment: For `event = event || window.event`, you need `event` as a formal parameter to the function.

Comment: event = event || window.event makes no difference to the code. The result is still that Event is not defined. How is it possible to define it within the code?

Comment: Did you look at the dupe?

Comment: yeah the dupe includes createEvent which is not supported

Answer (score 0):

See the comments in the code.

```js
function categoryClick() {
  var events = ["mousemove", "mouseover", "focus", "mousedown", "mouseup", "click"];
  var combobox = document.getElementById("category");
  var a = combobox.childNodes;
  var target = a[0].childNodes[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    if (typeof(Event) === 'function') { // just as you did
        var eventObject = new Event(events[i], {
          "bubbles": true,
          "cancelable": false
        })
    } else { // fallback for IE
        var eventObject = document.createEvent('Event');
        eventObject.initEvent(events[i], true, false);
    }

    target.dispatchEvent(eventObject);
  }
}
```