# Custom-Event from Internet explorer into visual-basic

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, custom-events

I need to listen to custom-event from a browsercontrol in a visual-basic program
A recent windowsupdate prevents vbscript from working

Our problem:
after windos update KB4490481 the internet explorer looses his VBScript capability!
I know that IE11 doesn't run VBScript anyway, but I'm talking about the browsercontrol, which is behaving as IE7 by default!

Well ok, so I converted the VBScript code to javascript, that seems fine
But it also uses Customevents, I used this help for it: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596123/internet-explorer-9-10-11-event-constructor-doesnt-work)

Seems ok, when you listen internaly to the event

But, I need the customevent to be raised to the mainprogram which contains the browsercontrol,
that doesn't work!

Unfortunately the mainprogram is written in VB6 (Visual Basic 6), so I don't find much help on it
My problem is, that "addEventListener" properly
with the help of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa752045(v=vs.94)
I'm able to lisen to non customevents like

```
Browser.Document.getElementById("btnMyButton").addEventListener "click", cfForward
```

but not to my customevent

```
Browser.Document.addEventListener "JSEvent", cfForward, False
```

Can anyone provide help?
I guess that working VBA Office Sample will also help me

The best thing for me would be a registry key to get vbscript back

Other things that don't help:
`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">` ==> had no effekt, vbscript doesn't run

rename the page to .hta:
Vbscript ist still working there, but there is a confirmation dialog, and it opens its own window

thanks
Donald

"btnMyButton" is a Button

`Browser.Document.getElementById("btnMyButton").addEventListener "click", cfForward` ==> is ok

"JSEvent" is a custom-event, that is fired onmousedown for testing

`Browser.Document.addEventListener "JSEvent", cfForward, False` ==> not ok

Comment: Before update to the KB4490481, whether the code works well? From [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4493509), it seems that the latest version is KB4493509, try to upgrade to the latest version. If still not working, please send us a simple sample to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I installed the newest updates, but it's still not working!

I made a simple Program to show what I'm trying to do:
the first button in the sample is directly wired via the "click" event to some code of the program, this is working
the second button calls a custom-event, which should call the program, this is not working

Why this custom event?
We are using a sort of event-hub, otherwise we must write really much eventhandler directly inside the VB6 program
If the problem can't be solved, we will have to this as a last resort

Comment: A word on the Testprogram:
just unpack it into any folder, open Javachecklist.vbp and run it.
Just note: browsercontrol must run as IE11, otherwise there will be errors
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
        DWORD vb6.exe = 11001 dec to run browsercontrol as IE11! 

Link to the sample program, valid for 3 days
https://spideroak.com/storage/MRSXA4BSO5SWE/shared/986859-2-9842/JSMini.zip?85a45ac74f5826b7d061f55f1c88a6ab